# Specifying band combinations when loading LANDSAT MTL files in ENVI IDL?

Tags: envi, idl

I'm somewhat new using ENVI and have a very limited background in programming. I was asked to compile 12 RGB and NIR composites of LANDSAT scenes within a specific timeframe and would like to use ENVI's IDL to not only create the composites with script but batch process each rather than do the 24 composites manually.

I have been looking around everywhere and the only somewhat helpful page has been https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ENVILayerStackRaster.html. However, I don't know how to call on specific bands from the MTL file to stack like I normally would when loading an MTL file into ENVI. All I can find is how to call on the OLI or TIRS bands as a group (https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/MetaspectralDatasets.html).

Once I figure that out then I'm onto the task of figuring out how to batch the process.
A little guidance would be helpful. I know I'm rushing into this without the proper foundation to be using IDL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ENVI Modeler to create your program even if you don't know IDL.

http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/modelergettingstarted.html

The Modeler makes it easy to create a batch process.